# transfer jpeg from c++ to android (java)

Tags: java, c++, android, sockets, taglib

I am struggling with the transfer of a simple jpeg file inside an ID3v2 tag from c++ over a TCP socket to java (Android). The library "taglib" offers to extract this file and I am able to save the jpeg as a new file.

The send function looks like this

```
char *parameter_full = new char[f3->picture().size()+2];
sprintf(parameter_full,"%s\n\0",f3->picture().data());

// send
result = send(c,parameter_full,strlen(parameter_full),0);

delete[] parameter_full;
```

where

f3->picture().data() returns a pointer to the internal data structure (it returns char*) and
f3->picture().size() returns the size of the array.

Then Android receives it with

```
String imageString = inFromServer.readLine();
byte[] imageBytes = imageString.getBytes();
Bitmap cover = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length);
```

But somehow decodeByteArray always returns null. My idea is that Java doesn't receive the image correctly because imageString only consists of 4 characters...while the extracted jpeg file has a size of 12.7 KB. 
But what has gone wrong?

Martin

Comment: Don't read it in as a string. It's not a string. Read it in as the raw bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use string functions on byte data because 0 values are taken as string terminators. Try looking into memcpy on the C++ side if you need to copy the `char*` and also the `byte[]` read functions for `InputStream` on the Java side.

Comment: Ah thanks for that hint! Now it's working. First I transmit file size in bytes (coverLength) and then every byte of the picture with send(c, f3->picture().data(), coverLength, 0).
The coverLength is received correctly but somehow the read(byte[], int, int) function stops too early.

int length = inputStream.read(imageBytes, 0, coverLength) always returns less than coverLength bytes...

Comment: Yes, you won't necessarily get the entire byte array at once. You should call read in a loop and keep track of how many bytes you read. Alternatively you could use Apache commons IOUtils, which has a nice utility method called `toByteArray`: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Ah the maximum packet size, thanks! IOUtils is not available in the Android SDK. After a hard struggle the transfer almost works now.
First, I send the length:

sprintf_s(buf, 10, "%d\n", coverLength); 
send(c,buf,strlen(buf),0);

and then the data fragments are sent. Simultaneously the data is read. The coverLength with 

inFromServer.readLine()

and the data with 

for (int count = 0; count < coverLength; count++) 
imageBytes[count] = (byte)inputStream.read();

But this only works when when I interrupt the sending procedure between. Otherwise read() blocks. What's wrong now?

Comment: Probably you are trying to read too many bytes from the stream. Try playing with `coverLength`. Also note that reading into byte arrays is much more efficient than reading one byte at a time.

Comment: I've also tried it with inputStream.read(imageBytes, 0, coverLength); but the problem stays. Even with a file of only 383 Bytes...Sorry :|

Comment: You have to check the byte count actually returned by `read` and then update your start and offset.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think the original problem is still present. Even with read() inside a while loop I can get it working - but only when I interrupt the sending procedure with the debugger. Otherwise read() always blocks and even inputStream.available() inside the while loop always returns 0 forever...

Comment: It blocks on the first call, so there is not a single block transmitted. It's like there are no bytes in the stream...